Encountered Error LinQToTwitter MVC Example
Hi I'm exploring the example of Twitter API V2 using LinQToTwitter library. I'm using  ASP.NET CORE, the target framework is net6.O. Upon trying it out, I'm encountering an error like this:

The code where I'm getting error. I don't know exactly where I should put the TwitterClientID nor the TwitterClientSecret. From what I have tested before the Twitter API V2, I'm using the Token secret...etc. These ones I'm not used to how to configure. Maybe somebody could redirect me to the right path. Thank you!
public async Task<ActionResult> BeginAsync()
 {
     string twitterCallbackUrl = Request.GetDisplayUrl().Replace("Begin", "Complete");

     var auth = new MvcOAuth2Authorizer
     {
         CredentialStore = new OAuth2SessionCredentialStore(HttpContext.Session)
         {
             ClientID = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(OAuthKeys.TwitterClientID),
             ClientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(OAuthKeys.TwitterClientSecret),
             
             Scopes = new List<string>
             {
                 "tweet.read",
                 "tweet.write",
                 "tweet.moderate.write",
                 "users.read",
                 "follows.read",
                 "follows.write",
                 "offline.access",
                 "space.read",
                 "mute.read",
                 "mute.write",
                 "like.read",
                 "like.write",
                 "block.read",
                 "block.write"
             },
             RedirectUri = twitterCallbackUrl,
         }
     };

     return await auth.BeginAuthorizeAsync("MyState");
 }

Hoping somebody has encountered something like this and help me to configure this stuff. Thank you!

you could try to store the OAuthKeys.TwitterClientID and OAuthKeys.TwitterClientSecret in environment variables or a secure configuration store. or for test you could try to directly set in the code and see if you are still getting the error or not. or else as mentioned in the below document you could also store the credential in the appsetting file and access like this in the code: twitterOptions.ConsumerKey = config["Authentication:Twitter:ConsumerAPIKey"];        twitterOptions.ConsumerSecret = config["Authentication:Twitter:ConsumerSecret"];

reference link: https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/tree/main
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio
